# How do I differentiate this with respect to x?

Tags: derivatives

I need to differentiate this equation with respect to $x$:

$$
u(x)=\left[x\left((1-\alpha)+\alpha\left(\frac{\pi(\hat{W}/x-1)}{P}\right)^{\frac{\psi-1}{\psi}}\right)^{\frac{\psi}{\psi-1}}\right]^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}},$$

or
$$u(x)=\left[x \ h(x) \right] ^{\frac{\sigma-1}{\sigma}},$$
where
$\alpha\in(0,1)$, $x>0$, $\psi>0$, $\psi\neq 1$ and $\sigma>0$. $\pi,P,\hat{W}$ are positive constants.

I need a solution expressed with the h-function. For example

$$u'(x) = ?? h(x) ^{??}. $$

Hope to hear from someone, 
thanks in advance